# A tighter relaxation of the mix logical constraints

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, logical-constraints, convex-hull

Suppose the following logical form there exists.

$$Iff: (x_{j,m} \land x_{k,m}) \implies ((C_{j} \leq S_{k}) \lor (C_{k} \leq S_{j}))$$

This is well-known as a ***no_overlap_constraint*** in the parallel machine scheduling problem. One of the linearization forms that is frequently used in literature is as:

$$C_{j} \leq S_{k} + M*(1-x_{j,m}) + M*(1-x_{k,m}) + M*(\alpha_{j,k}) \quad \forall k,j,m: j<k \tag1$$
$$C_{k} \leq S_{j} + M*(1-x_{j,m}) + M*(1-x_{k,m}) + M*(1-\alpha_{j,k}) \quad \forall k,j,m: j<k \tag2$$

This linearization still leads to a weak linear relaxation that already causes a long time to solve the problem. Hence, I tried to derive another linearization form based on the following CNF transformation:

$$ Iff: (x_{j,m} \land x_{k,m}) \implies ((w_{j,k}^1 \iff C_{j} \leq S_{k}) \lor (w_{j,k}^2 \iff C_{k} \leq S_{j}))$$
$$ Iff: (x_{j,m} \land x_{k,m}) \implies (w_{j,k}^1 \lor w_{j,k}^2) $$
$$ (1-x_{j,m}) + (1-x_{k,m}) + w_{j,k}^1 + w_{j,k}^2 \geq 1 \tag3 $$
$$ C_{j} \leq S_{k} + M*(1-w_{j,k}^1) \tag4 $$
$$ C_{j} \geq S_{k} + \epsilon - (M-\epsilon)*w_{j,k}^1 \tag5 $$
$$ C_{k} \leq S_{j} + M*(1-w_{j,k}^2) \tag6 $$
$$ C_{k} \geq S_{j} + \epsilon - (M-\epsilon)*w_{j,k}^2 \tag7 $$

After solving the model with both formulations, I found that the second one, $\{(3), (4), (5), (6), (7) \}$, can be solved so faster than the first one. The first transformation takes around 28 sec, while the second just takes around 2 sec. (for the same data and environment). In both cases, the optimal solution is the same and the results are reasonable.

1. **I would like to know if the second form is a correct derivation of the logical constraint(?) and if I am not lucky to get the optimal solution.**
2. **Is there any tighter formulation to speed up the solving process?**

Comment: What does Iff mean here? What is $\alpha_{ij}$? Your (1) and (2) use an unspecified $i$ index. Also, (1) and (2) mistakenly use $x_{jm}$ twice each.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks, and sorry for my typo. I just edited it. Actually, $\alpha_{j,k}$ is an auxiliary binary variable.

Comment: Any reason why is the 2nd formulation faster? There you have two more variables and 1 additional constraint.

Comment: @Sutanu, The second formulation in practice, yields more constraints and variables. Maybe this is one of the cases. I really would like to find a tighter formulation. I have not tried yet any analysis of how the second formulation may be near to the convex hull, but I am interested to see other formulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (3) through (7) yield a correct linearization of the original implication. But you don’t need to enforce $\iff$ for the $w$ variables, and so you can omit (5) and (7).

Comment: Many thanks for your hint. In some cases, I have seen they used $\iff$ to couple the variables. Would you please, say do you already have any suggestions for a tighter form?